# Random train/test split of all data rows spread over many csv-files with data generator (keras Sequence API)

Tags: python, csv, keras, neural-network

I'm training neural networks with keras and want to use data generators with keras' Sequence API. My data is stored in individual csv-files of various sizes, where the first 4 of the columns are the features/predictor variables (columns “A” to “D”) and the fifth column is the predicted variable (column “E”). So far, the train/test split is achieved between files, e.g., for a 0.2 test fraction and 1000 csv-files I'm simply using 800 training files and 200 testing files stored in separate directories (or, alternatively, using randomized indices or using `sklearn` `train_test_split`). This is how a lot of examples I found seem to do it.

Based on the nature of my data it would be beneficial if I can not only achieve this split between files, but between all available rows. That way the data would be even more randomized. E.g., if I have 1000 csv-files of various sizes and they contain a total number of 1,000,000 rows, I’d like 800,000 rows for training and 200,000 rows for testing. That means a file would have both training and testing rows.

Unfortunately, I can only think of ways of doing this when I add all csv-files together into memory. But the reason why I’m using data generators with keras’ Sequence API is that all files are too big to be handled that way, they need to be used in small batches. How I imagine this to work:

- `keras.model.fit()` takes two data generators, one for training (`train_generator`) and one for testing (`test_generator`). Both are based on the same data generator class
- `train_generator` goes through individual batches of files, applies the train/test splits based on the number of rows in the csv-files and uses the training rows
- `test_generator` *somehow remembers* (**this is the point where I need help**) which rows have been used for training before and uses the ones that remain

How can I adjust my data generator to do this? Here's a minimum example of my code that does the split between files and doesn't yet achieve the split between rows:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
     
    def __init__(self, list_of_csv_files, predictor_column_names, predicted_column_name, shuffle=True, batch_size=5):
        self.list_of_csv_files = list_of_csv_files
        self.predictor_column_names = predictor_column_names
        self.predicted_column_name = predicted_column_name
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self): # Updates/shuffles indexes after each epoch
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.list_of_csv_files)
            
    def __len__(self) :
        return np.ceil(len(self.list_of_csv_files) / float(self.batch_size)).astype(int)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx): # Generates one batch of data
        files_current_batch = self.list_of_csv_files[idx*self.batch_size : idx*self.batch_size + self.batch_size]
        X = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(s, usecols=self.predictor_column_names) for s in files_current_batch], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        y = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(s, usecols=self.predicted_column_name) for s in files_current_batch], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        X = np.array(X)
        y = np.array(y)
        return X, y

# define parameters for data generator
list_of_csv_files_train = glob.glob("/train_directory_name/" + "*.csv")
list_of_csv_files_test = glob.glob("/test_directory_name/" + "*.csv")
predictor_column_names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
predicted_column_name = ["E"]
batch_size = 5
# build model    
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile()    
# use data generators
train_generator = DataGenerator(list_of_csv_files_train, predictor_column_names, predicted_column_name, shuffle=True, batch_size=5)
test_generator = DataGenerator(list_of_csv_files_test, predictor_column_names, predicted_column_name, shuffle=True, batch_size=5)
# train model
model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=test_generator, epochs=num_epochs)
```

Comment: If the memory allows you to combine all the files in one large file, then you could do that random selection based on the rows.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "I can only think of ways of doing this when I add all csv-files together into memory" - but unfortunately all files together are too large